# How to find date periods between 2 dates?

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have 2 dates one is stored inside my date and for other date I am using calculated column in order to store the end date into that, how an I calculate the difference in time period between those dates, I need the date period between all those dates is that possible with DAX?

How can I use calculated column inside my DAX and also I dont have a calender table inside my database.

2019-05-31 and end date is 2019-06-03 then the difference will give me 3 dates that is 2019-05-31,2019-06-01 2019-06-02 and 2019-06-03

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible and easy. If you just need the difference between dates in two columns you can create a calculated column using the following:

```
DateDiff =
DATEDIFF ( 'Table'[Date1], 'Table'[Date2], DAY )
```

This will take the difference between Date1 and Date2 in days.

Comment: I need all the dates for example if my start date is 2019-05-31 and end date is 2019-06-03 then the difference will give me 3 dates that is 2019-05-31,2019-06-01 2019-06-02 and 2019-06-03

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @start_date [date] = CAST(‘2012-08-01’ as [date])
DECLARE @end_date [date] = CAST(‘2012-09-01’ as [date])
SELECT
DATEADD(day, [v].[number], @start_date)
FROM
[master].[dbo].[spt_values] [v]
WHERE
[v].[type] = ‘P’ AND
DATEADD(day, [v].[number], @start_date) <= @end_date
```

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation, in order to help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free coding service. Also, have a look here to get your post look like intended: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and read [answer] and take the [tour].